# Matching multiple iterations of a word with regex

Tags: regex, bash, macos

I am trying to craft some regex that can match all of the following strings (no more, no less):

```
ftp
ftps
sftp
ftpes
```

The closest I have gotten is: `^ftps?$` but as you can tell that only matches the top two. How can I match all of the ones listed? I am aware that I can use something like `^(ftp|ftps|sftp|ftpes)$` but I wanted to save as much space as possible (my actual application is much much larger than this so space saving is more necessary. I used the ftp example for visual appeal).

I am using this in a bash 3.2.57(1)-release if-statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest this extended regex:

```
^(ftpe?s|s?ftp)$
```

> `ftpe?s`: one `e` is optional
>
> `s?ftp`: one `s` is optional

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

A variation on an extended regex would be:

```
^(s?ftp|^ftp(s|es)?)$
```

Here:

- `(^s?ftp|` zero or one `'s'` followed by `ftp` at the beginning
- or
- `ftp` followed by `(s|es)?$` zero or one `'s'` or `'es'` after.

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks, but this also matches `sftpes`.

Comment: Sent an edit, I replaced `{0,1}` with `?` since they both work the same.